# What is a good encryptable disk image format suitable for rsync on a PC?

Tags: windows-xp, encryption, rsync, disk-image

I’m looking for a solution to encrypt my XP home directory and then rsync the encrypted image file to a remote server.

Since I don’t want to transfer several Gigs for even the smallest change in the image I’m looking for a solution which saves the image “chunked”  into smaller files. That way Rsync can transfer only the changed elements.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an uncompressed encrypted disk image with a small block size, small changes to the partition will result in small changes to the encrypted image, which is suitable for rsync. Truecrypt should do the trick.

It wouldn't be beneficial (from the perspective of rsync) to split up the image into different files, because rsync doesn't look for common data across files, only in the same file.

Comment: "rsync doesn't look for common data across files, only in the same file" - note that rsync has a --fuzzy option for something like that. May not apply to this situation but I thought I'd mention it.